# Jquery checkbox toggling only on checking unchecking and then checking

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I want to show a div on checking a checkbox and hide the div on unchecking the checkbox.This is what I tried.It works only on checking and unchecking and then checking. I am using jquery 3.5.1.

I think there is a problem with this jquery part logic

jquery part

```
$('.frameopener').on('change', function(){ // on change of state
   if(this.checked) // if changed state is "CHECKED"
    {
       
           var formid=$(this).attr("id");
 
       $("#"+formid+"").click(function() {
   
  $("#" + formid + "form").toggle();
    
});

}
});
```

php part which dynamically displays checkbox from a loop

```
echo '
 
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="frameopener" id="'.$checkboxitemsafterstripper[$key].'" ></td><td>'.
   $item.'
  </td>';
```

Here is the  frame which needs to be toggled

```
foreach( $checkboxitemsafterstripper as $key => $item ){
echo '
<div id="'.$item.'form">';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you have use `$("#"+formid+"").click(function() {..` there is no need to use this simply get id of checkbox and toggle div .

***Demo code*** :

```js
$("div[id$=form]").hide() //hide all div whose id end with form
$('.frameopener').on('change', function() { // on change of state
  var formid = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#" + formid + "form").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="frameopener" id="12">12
<input type="checkbox" class="frameopener" id="13">13
<input type="checkbox" class="frameopener" id="14">14

<div id="12form">12 div</div>
<div id="13form">13 div</div>
<div id="14form">14 div</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much swathi.This was what i was looking for.You corrected me thank you so much